# Moving Azure blob storage files from one folder to another

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to copy files from one folder to another in the same blob container (IE: everything in `container/processing` to `container/archived`). The following code creates the target folder and files but it's always 0 bytes. What is wrong with this code? I've tried using just a single stream, same problem. _blobServiceClient is the type [BlobServiceClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobserviceclient?view=azure-dotnet). If I download and serialize the object to a C# class and then re-upload it, it works. But I'd prefer to make this as efficient as possible since I'm just moving things around in BlobStorage and don't actually need to use the contents in my code.

```
var containerClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(container);
var blobHierarchyItems = containerClient.GetBlobsByHierarchy(BlobTraits.None, BlobStates.None, null, sourceFolder);

foreach (var bhi in blobHierarchyItems)
{
    using (var downStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var upStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(bhi.Blob.Name);
        blobClient.DownloadTo(downStream);
        containerClient.UploadBlob($"{targetFolder}/{bhi.Blob.Name}", upStream);
        downStream.Position = 0;
        await downStream.CopyToAsync(upStream);
    }
}
```

I've also tried using a `BlockBlobClient.StartCopyFromUriAsync` function. The results are the same, it creates the target folder and blob but no data. Here's that code:

```
var containerClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(container);
var blobHierarchyItems = containerClient.GetBlobs(BlobTraits.None, BlobStates.None, sourceFolder);
var targetBlockClient = containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(targetFolder);

foreach (var bhi in blobHierarchyItems)
{
    var blobUri = new Uri($"{containerClient.Uri}/{bhi.Name}");
    var copyOp = await targetBlockClient.StartCopyFromUriAsync(blobUri);
    await copyOp.WaitForCompletionAsync();
}
```

Source folder

[image]

Target folder

[image]

Comment: Why are you downloading and uploading? Can’t you simply copy the blob from source to destination?

Comment: It looks like you can use [`StartCopyFromUriAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.startcopyfromuriasync?view=azure-dotnet) and [`WaitForCompletionAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.copyfromurioperation.waitforcompletionasync?view=azure-dotnet) to perform a copy that doesn't go through your machine.

Comment: The reason for the problem you describe is that you upload `upStream` _before_ you copy `downStream` into it.

Comment: I don't want to download and upload, just copy would be ideal.. just haven't found anything that works yet.. unfortunately the api's have changed quite drastically from asp.net core 2->3 so having trouble finding the right way to do it

Comment: @KirkLarkin I tried StartCopyFromUriAsync originally and believe I got an error.. will try again and post results

Comment: Just one thing to keep in mind: No such thing as "folders" in Azure Blob Storage (unless you enable hierarchical storage). The folder name is just part of the blob's name.

Comment: @DavidMakogon pretty sure we're using Hierarchical storage

Comment: @KirkLarkin I updated the question after trying StartCopyFromUriAsync

Comment: @KirkLarkin actually StartCopyFromUriAsync is working, it's just not keeping the full path for the source and copying that path to the target.. I'm looking into fixing that

Comment: @KirkLarkin this works, thanks
                var targetBlockClient = containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient($"{targetFolder}/{bhi.Name}");
                var blobUri = new Uri($"{containerClient.Uri}/{bhi.Name}");

Comment: I added my solution to the other question linked above